# Apache FOP - Scrolling in PDF possible?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP to generate a PDF through XML and XSL-FO. I have a cell in my generated PDF that I need to be able to scroll through if the content overflows it. XSL-FO has an overflow="scroll" feature, but based on my research on the topic it seems that Apache FOP does not support this option.

For example, here is a scrollable region in a PDF used by a large CAD company that I need to replicate:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to enable this feature in Apache FOP? Is it possible to enable it in the source code (I haven't been able to find a way to do so)? Any other ways to tackle this issue?

Comment: I think I've never seen any pdf wherin you could scroll one cell, did you?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://imgur.com/qbOvK1T) is a scrollable region in a PDF used by a large CAD company that I need to replicate.

Comment: Interesting ... Is it part of a form? Another possible explanation is a javascript action.

Comment: I currently only have a screenshot and assumed it was just a regular PDF, but if as you say this is not possible in a standard PDF then perhaps it is an interactive PDF form -- I will confirm this later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, it isn't possible.

### From the FO perspective:

In the [XSL-FO Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#overflow) the `scroll` value for the property `overflow` comes **from the corresponding CSS2 definition**, which includes this clarification:

> When this value is specified and the target medium is "print", overflowing content should be printed.

As the PDF output is a print-oriented medium, I read this as a confirmation that FOP is correct in printing the overflowing content.

### From the PDF perspective:

In the [PDF Reference 6th edition](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), a search for the word "scroll" returns results referring either to the scrolling bars in the **user interface** or in **interactive forms** (text fields, list boxes, combo boxes).

There is not, or at least I could not find it, a "static text object, but with scrolling bars" feature (which is probably sensible for a print-oriented format), so FOP cannot create it in the PDF output file, *not even modifying the source code*.

A second look at your comment and the screenshot you included made me think it could be an example of the [3D Artwork](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf#789) feature of the PDF format, a feature I didn't know of before (and I still know nothing besides its name). According to the reference:

> Specific views of 3D artwork can be specified, including a default view that is displayed initially and **other views that can be selected**. **Views can have names that can be presented in a user interface**.

So, I think your screenshot shows the different views associated to a 3D object; it is not a general-purpose feature that could be used to provide scrollable text.

Comment: Ok. So then could I manually post-process the FOP-generated PDF into an interactive PDF form to change the field into a scrollable box? How about automatically -- any way you know of that this can be done?

Comment: @Gerk I updated the answer with a possible explanation of your screenshot. However, the point still remains valid: to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to have scrollable text in a PDF.

Comment: That is likely a RichMedia PDF annotation which is Flash driven by XML that can be stored in the PDF. I will provide a separate answer under the spirit of "Is their any other ways..."

Answer (score 4):

### Well, it could be possible ...

It is possible but as far as I know not with Apache FOP. Without seeing the PDF in question and guessing from the screen shot, it looks like a Flash widget inserted into the PDF. This in PDF terms is a RichMedia annotation (requires PDF version 1.7 with extensions) in which you can insert the Flash widget as well as other controlling files (like XML, other images to display, etc.) and relate them together.

AFAIK, only RenderX XEP (whom I work for) supports such RichMedia annotations inserted into PDF via XSL FO through the rx:rich-media-object extension documented here: [http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#Rich Media](http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#Rich%20Media)

I believe, the only viewer that supports PDF with RichMedia annotations is Adobe Reader so it is required to view such a file. Here is a sample that includes a few interactive flash widgets, some interactive charts all within a few page PDF that was generated long ago. NOTE: I am sure some of the links in the document do not go anywhere, it was for a trade show many years ago. **Remember, you would need to download this file and view in Adobe Reader and have flash player installed to see it function.**

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Resources/Samples/RichMedia.pdf

**You cannot use common PDF browser-based viewers like Chrome or Firefox as they do not support this type of annotation.**

A screenshot of page one here shows an interactive, scrolling widget. Page 4 contains a widget similar to what you show in your example.

[image]

Page 4 scrolling widget very similar to your request:

[image]

The widget on the last page is created using a scroller SWF that takes parameters that are the images and setup/configuration files that are XML. The RenderX extension object takes these as parameters and embeds all of them in the document for the interactive flash widget so that it is totally self-contai9ned in the PDF. The XSL FO to do this is:

```
    <rx:rich-media-object name="Sample HTML Widget" scaling="non-uniform" width="611.92pt"
        height="74.99pt" content-width="scale-to-fit" src="url('rx-scroller\dockmenu.swf')"
        transparency="true" activate-condition="page_visible">
        <rx:flash-var name="setupXML" value="rx-dock-settings.xml"/>
        <rx:flash-var name="contentXML" value="rx-dock-contents.xml"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="rx-dock-settings.xml"
            src="url('rx-scroller\rx-dock-settings.xml')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="rx-dock-contents.xml"
            src="url('rx-scroller\rx-dock-contents.xml')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="style.css" src="url('rx-scroller\css\style.css')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer1.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer1.png')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer2.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer2.png')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer3.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer3.png')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer4.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer4.png')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer5.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer5.png')"/>
        <rx:rich-media-resource name="customer6.png" src="url('rx-scroller\images\customer6.png')"/>
    </rx:rich-media-object>
```

And note that many things that are in the flash would work, like links and such. It is just a pure, interactive flash inserted into PDF as the container.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Kevin. This product looks very cool and promising, but I don't think my company would be willing to spend thousands of dollars just to get a scrollable region inside of a PDF working.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it looks like this is not possible to achieve through FOP.

Continuing to dig around for a few days, however, I did find a clever [post-processing alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283564/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-scrollable-frame-inside-a-pdf?answertab=votes#tab-top) that is also free, essentially embedding a PDF inside of another PDF using the LaTeX animate package.

A drawback to this method is that it is not possible to embed links inside of the scrollable region, which is a major issue for me. But the method does enable inserting a scrollable region inside of an existing PDF and got me very close to what I was trying to achieve.